# How to print all the words that have been written into many possibilities

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make for example, I have 3 keywords Apple, Orange, and Banana. I want these three keywords to be printed randomly, for example:

1. Apple Orange Banana
2. Orange Banana Apple
3. Banana Apple Orange
4. etc

until the possibilities run out

I've written to randomize the keywords, but the code I wrote can only print 1 sentence. how to print multiple sentences at once until the possibilities run out?

This is my Code

```
import random

words = ('Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange')
result = ''.join(random.sample(words, k=len(words)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/3135025

Comment: It could also be `permutations` that might also work here? Depending on what specific behaviour you are looking for. It's not clear which one (permutation vs combination) would work better for whatever the ultimate goal is. But, `from itertools import permutations; list(permutations(words))`. Run that and you can see what that looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.permutations`

```
import itertools
words = ('Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange')
result = list(itertools.permutations(words))
print (result)
```

This gets you all combinations but in same order every time you execute the code. You can shuffle it randomly using `numpy`

```
import numpy
numpy.random.shuffle (result)
```